# POST vs GET method in Django's view function

Tags: python, django

My app's urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'javascript'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create_table', views.create_table, name='create_table')
```

My views.py is:

```
def create_table(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        row_data = "this is row data"
        context = {'row_data': row_data}
return render(request, 'javascript/create_table.html',context)
```

My create_table.html is:

```
{% load static %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="create_table">Get data</button>
</form>
<div id="place_for_table"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var row_data = "{{ row_data }}"
</script>
<script src="{% static 'javascript/scripts/create_table.js' %}"></script>
```

And my create_table.js is:

```
function create_table() {
    document.getElementById("place_for_table").innerHTML = row_data;
}
document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function() {
    create_table()
}
```

What I want to achieve is: when the `/create table` URL is requested, only the button is displayed. When the button is pressed, `row_data` variable's value is displayed below the button.

At this moment the data is displayed for a blink of an eye and then disappears.

I guess I am not distinguishing between POST and GET methods correctly in the view function. Also I have based my logic on the assumption that URL is requested using GET method by default. However if I put a `print(request.method)` at the beginning of my view, it prints POST.

Also, whenever I load the page for the first time or refresh it, I get a Firefox warning:"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Other things I tried was to use class-based view with post and get defs or put the create_table's URL in `button formaction=` tag, but that doesn't help.

I would be thankful for any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: It sounds like your button might be submitting the form after running `create_table()`. So it runs `create_table()` then a split second later the post of the form causes your browser to get a response and the whole page is re-rendered. That would explain why you see the data flash for a split second before disappearing again

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Do you have any idea how to prevent the button to submit a form? (also, isn't it strange that it is submitting a form even though it is not of "submit" type?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because when you are `submitting` the form it `refreshes/reloads` your  page i.e. `/create_table` url because of which row_data `resets`

[This](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)  Might help you to understand why the button submits even though you didn't explicitly provided `type="submit"` to the button inside your form.

Our aim will be to prevent the event to occur. It can be done using a simple  `return false` statement in our `onclick` listener as given below:

```
 function create_table() {
        document.getElementById("place_for_table").innerHTML = row_data;
 }   
 document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function(event) {
        create_table();
        return false;
 }
```